# Applying a command to the current line in less?

Tags: shell, ls, less

Let's say we list `/usr/bin` with `ls` – this may look like:

```
CC                file2c            man               sscop
Mail              find              mandoc            ssh
addftinfo         finger            manpath           ssh-add
addr2line         flex              merge             ssh-agent
...
```

but we could also use `ls -1`, and we get:

```
CC
Mail
addftinfo
addr2line
afmtodit
alias
apply
apropos
...
```

A list with all filenames, each of them in a single line. The structure of the output is: filename, newline (`\n`), …

This we can pipe to `less`: `ls -1 | less`.

Now, is it possible to easily apply a command to the string contained in the current line?

How exactly this is done is irrelevant, just the number of steps should be small. It could be by using `!` in less (this doesn't seem possible?) or by *somehow* getting the string contained in the current line into a shell variable etc.

Under Xorg this is easy of course, by just using the middle mouse button paste. But in text mode, *can* one do it in a not too complicated way?

Comment: What does `pasting` have to with that? Don't you rather want to *copy* the top line?

Comment: OK, I see.  You can easily do what you want with `GNU screen` or `tmux` but you'd have to have it started before opening `less`.

Comment: @don_crissti It's in all details described in the question and it seems the two answering posters understood it, too. What's still unclear about the question?

Comment: @don_crissti what `pick` can do (or `mc`): Interactively searching in a directory for a filename and then applying a command to the found file. But obviously, doing it with basic unix tools. To a certain degree it can be done with vi**m**, which is nearly always installed, yet only in a cumbersome way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`|` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) to pipe part of the file through another program, but that part is always at least two lines. You can hack it together with marks and [`tail`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html), though:

1. With the line you want at the top, press <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (or any other letter for the second one).
2. Scroll up one line with <kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>Up</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>|</kbd> and then the letter you chose in place of <kbd>a</kbd> above.
4. Type `tail -n 1 | ...`, where `...` is any command that will be given that one line as its standard input.

`tail -n 1` will give us only the second line, which is the one we care about. `...` gets that line to do with as it wishes.

If you want to use the line as an argument to a command instead of standard input, you can [use `xargs` or another wrapper](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html):

```
tail -n 1 | xargs ls -l
```

If that command displays anything, it won't remain visible on the screen, but you can pipe it to `less` again:

```
tail -n 1 | xargs ls -l | less
```

This will be a nested `less`: you quit it, and then you're back in the original `less`, and can repeat the process.

---

If the command is interactive somehow, like a text editor, and doesn't like having its standard input be a pipe or null, you can use a [`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) process in the middle to run the command and reopen the tty:

```
xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" < /dev/tty' sh
```

BSD `xargs` also has a `-o` option to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be:

1. Move to the desired start of selection (for example, by searching for it).
2. <kbd>m</kbd> followed by some letter, say <kbd>X</kbd> to set mark.
3. Move to the end of the selection.
4. <kbd>|</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> (this will switch to `!` prompt, where you are expected to write a command which will be given the the selection on the stdin.
5. Type the command and press <kbd>RET</kbd>